# Add new field to every document in a MongoDB collection

Tags: mongodb, field, nosql

How can I add a new field to every document in an existent collection?

I know how to update an existing document's field but not how to add a new field to every document in a collection. How can I do this in the `mongo` shell?

Answer (score 756, accepted):

Same as the updating existing collection field, [`$set`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-$set) will add a new fields if the specified field does not exist.

Check out this example:

```
> db.foo.find()
> db.foo.insert({"test":"a"})
> db.foo.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e93037bbf6f1dd3a0a9541a"), "test" : "a" }
> item = db.foo.findOne()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e93037bbf6f1dd3a0a9541a"), "test" : "a" }
> db.foo.update({"_id" :ObjectId("4e93037bbf6f1dd3a0a9541a") },{$set : {"new_field":1}})
> db.foo.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e93037bbf6f1dd3a0a9541a"), "new_field" : 1, "test" : "a" }
```

**EDIT:**

In case you want to add a new_field to all your collection, you have to use empty selector, and set multi flag to true (last param) to update all the documents

```
db.your_collection.update(
  {},
  { $set: {"new_field": 1} },
  false,
  true
)
```

**EDIT:**

In the above example last 2 fields `false, true` specifies the `upsert` and `multi` flags.

**Upsert:**  If set to true, creates a new document when no document matches the query criteria.

**Multi:**   If set to true, updates multiple documents that meet the query criteria. If set to false, updates one document.

This is for Mongo `versions` prior to `2.2`. For latest versions the query is changed a bit

```
db.your_collection.update({},
                          {$set : {"new_field":1}},
                          {upsert:false,
                          multi:true})
```

Comment: Is it possible to create without value

Comment: db.your_collection.update({},
                          {$set : {"new_field":null}},
                          {upsert:false,
                          multi:true})

Comment: what if I want  to create an empty array?

Comment: @PrashantPokhriyal db.your_collection.update({}, {$set : {"new_field":[]}}, {upsert:false, multi:true})

Comment: What if you want to create the new field with the value assigned dynamically? For example, I would like to have `new_field` to be an int equal to the length of the string in `test` field.

Comment: Is it possible to insert field  after specific field ?  as of now it inserted after end of last field.

Comment: @thePolarExpress88, I am not sure if thats possible. Is there any reason why you want to do that??

Comment: I just get "Cannot use (or request) retryable writes with multi=true"

Comment: I want to fill the field with `Math.random()` how can i achieve that every document gets another value?

Comment: i test it, it's worked. but value is double! can i set it as integer?

Comment: Question asks for multiple documents but the example only shows one document being updated.

Comment: @RameshVel can you please  tell , how to do add the same attribute while working with mongodb atlas, but not mongo shell.

Comment: @RameshVel can you tell me how does it work with flask and mongoengine?

Comment: 'DeprecationWarning: Collection.update() is deprecated. Use updateOne, updateMany or bulkWrite.'

Comment: Does this update command locks collection or just a document when multi set as true

Comment: What is the difference with `updateMany`?

Answer (score 91):

Since MongoDB version 3.2 you can use [updateMany()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/):

```
> db.yourCollection.updateMany({}, {$set:{"someField": "someValue"}})
```

Comment: I think `updateMany` is more readable

Comment: How can I implement it to an array of objects? like ```some_arr[{_id:1},{_id:2},{_id:1}]```. I want to add a new field status to each object in the array in all MongoDB documents in a collection

Answer (score 28):

To clarify, the syntax is as follows for MongoDB version 4.0.x:

```
db.collection.update({},{$set: {"new_field*":1}},false,true)
```

Here is a working example adding a *published* field to the *articles* collection and setting the field's value to *true*:

```
db.articles.update({},{$set: {"published":true}},false,true)
```

Comment: Using `updateMany` will be more right

Answer (score 25):

```
db.collection.updateMany({}, {$set: {"fieldName": ""}})
```

`updateMany` requires a matching condition for each document, since we are passing `{}` it is always true. And the second argument uses `$set` operator to add the required field in each document.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 6):

**Pymongo 3.9+**

[`update()` is now deprecated](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update) and you should use `replace_one()`, `update_one()`, or `update_many()` instead.

In my case I used [`update_many()`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_many) and it solved my issue:

```
db.your_collection.update_many({}, {"$set": {"new_field": "value"}}, upsert=False, array_filters=None)
```

Comment: Is it "update_many" or "updateMany" ?

Comment: @Abdulhakim it's [`update_many`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_many)

Comment: Hey guys, can I add a new field to each document from an array which is having a different value for each document.

Comment: @JAbr I don't know the answer, but better open a new question, because unless they're follow-ups to the original question, people don't usually answer new questions in the comments.

Comment: @AlexJolig for Mongodb shell, it's [`updateMany`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#mongodb-method-db.collection.updateMany)

Answer (score 2):

if you are using mongoose try this,after mongoose connection

```
async ()=> await Mongoose.model("collectionName").updateMany({}, {$set: {newField: value}})
```

Comment: hey @Edgar can you explain this in more detail by taking an example, and can you share documents , where you have found this?

Comment: hi @RohanDevaki , yes, https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html in "Updating" sections, in that page you see the example: "Tank" model = Mongoose.model("Tank") and the updateMany function you can find in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/

Comment: but while setting a new filed, you also need to mention the type of the new field right, where did you mention the type, and you have to add, whether it is required or not, how will you add these?

Answer (score 2):

The answers above does't cover this scenario. I was looking for the similar query but want to add `fields` to few documents based on condition.

So, we can use first variable of `updateMany` to update fields only in few documents.

**Example:** I want to add a nullable field `isDeprecated?` to all those Users whose userType is Employer and has country "AAA".

```
db.users.updateMany({"userType": "Employer", "country": "AAA"}, {"$set": { "isDeprecated?": true }})
```

This answer will be helpful in those scenarios as well, where we have to find the collection and then update. This can we done in single query like mentioned.