# Add field with value to existing document in MongoDB via Java API

Tags: java, mongodb

The following code haven't worked for me:

```
public void addFieldWithValueToDoc(String DBName, String collName, String docID, String key, String value) {
    BasicDBObject setNewFieldQuery = new BasicDBObject().append("$set", new BasicDBObject().append(key, value));
    mongoClient.getDB(DBName).getCollection(collName).update(new BasicDBObject().append("_id", docID), setNewFieldQuery);
}
```

Where mongoClient variable's type is MongoClient.

It's inspired by [Add new field to a collection in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714216/add-new-field-to-a-collection-in-mongodb) .
What's wrong and how to do it right?
Thanks.

Comment: Your code should work. One thing can be the `_id` field. Is it really `String` or `ObjectId`? If the later is true, change your code to `append("_id", new ObjectId(docID))`

Comment: @orid is almost certainly correct - String docID will not match ObjectId() type.

Comment: In what way hasn't it worked?  Was there an error, or did you not get the result you expected?  Also, you don't need to do `new BasicDBObject().append(key, value)` you can simply do `new BasicDBObject(key, value)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've written a JUnit test to prove that your code does work:

```
@Test
public void shouldUpdateAnExistingDocumentWithANewKeyAndValue() {
    // Given
    String docID = "someId";
    collection.save(new BasicDBObject("_id", docID));
    assertThat(collection.find().count(), is(1));

    // When
    String key = "newKeyName";
    String value = "newKeyValue";
    addFieldWithValueToDoc(db.getName(), collection.getName(), docID, key, value);

    // Then
    assertThat(collection.findOne().get(key).toString(), is(value));
}

public void addFieldWithValueToDoc(String DBName, String collName, String docID, String key, String value) {
    BasicDBObject setNewFieldQuery = new BasicDBObject().append("$set", new BasicDBObject().append(key, value));
    mongoClient.getDB(DBName).getCollection(collName).update(new BasicDBObject().append("_id", docID), setNewFieldQuery);
}
```

So your code is correct, although I'd like to point out some comments on style that would make it more readable:

1. Parameters and variables should start with a lower-case letter.  `DBName` should be `dbName`,
2. You don't need `new BasicDBObject().append(key, value)` use `new BasicDBObject(key, value)`

This code does the same thing as your code, but is shorter and simpler:

```
public void addFieldWithValueToDoc(String dbName, String collName, String docID, String key, String value) {
    mongoClient.getDB(dbName).getCollection(collName).update(new BasicDBObject("_id", docID),
                                                             new BasicDBObject("$set", new BasicDBObject(key, value)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> To update existing documents in a collection, you can use the collection’s updateOne() or updateMany methods.

updateOne method has the following [form](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/#db.collection.updateOne):

```
db.collection.updateOne(filter, update, options)
```

> **filter** - the selection criteria for the update. The same query selectors as in the find() method are available.
>
> Specify an empty document { } to update the first document returned in
>   the collection.
>
> **update** - the modifications to apply.

So, if you want to add one more field using Mongodb Java driver 3.4+, it will be:

```
collection.updateOne(new Document("flag", true),
                        new Document("$set", new Document("title", "Portable Space Ball")));
```

The following operation updates a single document where `flag:true`

Or in the same logic:

```
collection.updateOne(eq("flag", true),
                            new Document("$set", new Document("title", "Portable Space Ball")));
```

If the `title` field does not exist, [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#up._S_set) will add a new field with the specified value, provided that the new field does not violate a type constraint. If you specify a dotted path for a non-existent field, `$set` will create the embedded documents as needed to fulfill the dotted path to the field.