# Search value in nested array without index in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

My mongoDB schema as below .

```
"interpretationlist": [
{
    "interpretations": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "value": "value1"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "value": "value2"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "interpretations": [
        {
            "id": "3",
            "value": "value3"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

and I want to search `interpretation` whose `id` is `1` and update its value.
How can I do this.
no idea how can I do this.

Comment: I think this question may help you `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714216/add-new-field-to-a-collection-in-mongodb`

Comment: i don't want to add new field, i want to update value in array.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23577123/update-nested-array-with-mongoose-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

Hi I don't know how to do this in mongo query but I write below script which will solve your problem

```
         db.collectionName.find({
     "interpretationlist": {
         "$exists": true
     }
     }).forEach(function(data) {
     for (var i = 0; i < data.interpretationlist.length; i++) {
         for (var j = 0; j < data.interpretationlist[i].interpretations.length; j++) {
             var query = {};
             var updateQuery = {};
             findkey = [];
             findkey.push("interpretationlist." + i + ".interpretations." + j + ".id");
             query[findkey] = "1";
             updateQuery[findkey] = "20";
             db.collectionName.update(query, {
                 "$set": updateQuery
             }, false, false);
         }
     }
     })
```