# how to add fields in a single document in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am new to MongoDB and I have the following documents:

---

```
{
    "_id":ObjectID("55b89409b7d7df8c3d201618"),  
    "name":"John" 
}, 
{ 
    "_id":ObjectID("55b14359b7d7df8c3d20161c"), 
    "name":"Bahubali",  
    "products":7,  
    "contact_no":8819936800 
}
```

---

I need to edit the document which has the name `"John"`. I need to add more fields to this document. But, when I use `update`, it can update only the specific `name` field and when I use `save`, it replaces the existing document with new document.

Is there any other approach to add new fields to the above document without using `save`. Because whenever we use save, we will require to rewrite the whole document.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add new field to a collection in MongoDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714216/add-new-field-to-a-collection-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator for it:

Example:

```
db.products.update(
   { name: "John" },
   { $set:
      {
        quantity: 500,
        details: { model: "14Q3", make: "xyz" },
        tags: [ "coats", "outerwear", "clothing" ]
      }
   }
)
```

Comment: Edit this to be relevant to the information asked in the question and I'll give you a smiley stamp for your effort. Explain why it is better and two smiley stamps

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your mongoShell.

```
db.yourCollection.updateMany({"name":"john"}, {$set:{"products":7, "contact_no":8819936800}})
```