# how to add array in already exist document using nodejs?

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

I want to insert array in already exist documents .

now my document look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5604f0150fe136e9292ee16a"),
    "name" : "mamy",
    "url_Address" : "http://www.flipkart.com/mamy-poko-pants-diaper-large/p/itmdbdffn8gjzpfz?pid=DPRDADE2Z8BZGYZG&ref=L%3A-2196533682561335257&srno=p_1&query=mamy&otracker=from-search",
    "vendor_Name" : "WS Retail",
    "vendor_rating" : "4.2 / 5",
    "last_price_1" : "Rs. 699",
    "last_price_2" : "Rs. 699",
    "prce" : "Rs. 699",
    "product_Name" : "Mamy Poko Pants Diaper - Large",
    "MRP" : "Rs 573"
}
```

and i want to add an array in this with name competitor :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5604f0150fe136e9292ee16a"),
    "name" : "mamy",
    "url_Address" : "http://www.flipkart.com/mamy-poko-pants-diaper-large/p/itmdbdffn8gjzpfz?pid=DPRDADE2Z8BZGYZG&ref=L%3A-2196533682561335257&srno=p_1&query=mamy&otracker=from-search",
    "vendor_Name" : "WS Retail",
    "vendor_rating" : "4.2 / 5",
    "last_price_1" : "Rs. 699",
    "last_price_2" : "Rs. 699",
    "prce" : "Rs. 699",
    "product_Name" : "Mamy Poko Pants Diaper - Large",
    "MRP" : "Rs 573",
    "Competitor : [{
                     "cat_id" : "xx",
                     "name" : "mamy",
                     "url_Address" : "http://www.flipkart.com/mamy-poko-pants-diaper-large/p/itmdbdffn8gjzpfz?pid=DPRDADE2Z8BZGYZG&ref=L%3A-2196533682561335257&srno=p_1&query=mamy&otracker=from-search",
                     "vendor_Name" : "WS Retail",
                     "vendor_rating" : "4.2 / 5",
                     "last_price_1" : "Rs. 699",
                     "last_price_2" : "Rs. 699",
                     "prce" : "Rs. 699",
                     "product_Name" : "Mamy Poko Pants Diaper - Large",
                     "MRP" : "Rs 573"
                    },
                  {
                     "cat_id" : "xxx",
                     "name" : "mamy",
                      "url_Address" : "http://www.flipkart.com/mamy-poko-pants-diaper-large/p/itmdbdffn8gjzpfz?pid=DPRDADE2Z8BZGYZG&ref=L%3A-2196533682561335257&srno=p_1&query=mamy&otracker=from-search",
                     "vendor_Name" : "WS Retail",
                     "vendor_rating" : "4.2 / 5",
                     "last_price_1" : "Rs. 699",
                     "last_price_2" : "Rs. 699",
                     "prce" : "Rs. 699",
                     "product_Name" : "Mamy Poko Pants Diaper - Large",
                     "MRP" : "Rs 573"
                   }]"
}
```

what query i have to write in mongodb ?

what query i have to write in Nodejs ?

Comment: Here is your answer for mongodb query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714216/add-new-field-to-a-collection-in-mongodb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add whole `Competitor` array in existing document with update given in [doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/)

The query will be as:

```
db.collection.update({
    "_id": ObjectId("5604f0150fe136e9292ee16a")
}, {
    $set: {
    "Competitor": [{
        "cat_id": "xx",
        "name": "mamy",
        "url_Address": "http://www.flipkart.com/mamy-poko-pants-diaper-large/p/itmdbdffn8gjzpfz?pid=DPRDADE2Z8BZGYZG&ref=L%3A-2196533682561335257&srno=p_1&query=mamy&otracker=from-search",
        "vendor_Name": "WS Retail",
        "vendor_rating": "4.2 / 5",
        "last_price_1": "Rs. 699",
        "last_price_2": "Rs. 699",
        "prce": "Rs. 699",
        "product_Name": "Mamy Poko Pants Diaper - Large",
        "MRP": "Rs 573"
    }, {
        "cat_id": "xxx",
        "name": "mamy",
        "url_Address": "http://www.flipkart.com/mamy-poko-pants-diaper-large/p/itmdbdffn8gjzpfz?pid=DPRDADE2Z8BZGYZG&ref=L%3A-2196533682561335257&srno=p_1&query=mamy&otracker=from-search",
        "vendor_Name": "WS Retail",
        "vendor_rating": "4.2 / 5",
        "last_price_1": "Rs. 699",
        "last_price_2": "Rs. 699",
        "prce": "Rs. 699",
        "product_Name": "Mamy Poko Pants Diaper - Large",
        "MRP": "Rs 573"
    }]
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace document to add fields:

```
var updateRestaurants = function(db, callback) {
   db.collection('restaurants').replaceOne(
      { "restaurant_id" : "41704620" },
      {
        "name" : "Vella 2",
        "address" : {
           "coord" : [ -73.9557413, 40.7720266 ],
           "building" : "1480",
           "street" : "2 Avenue",
           "zipcode" : "10075"
        }
      },
      function(err, results) {
        console.log(results);
        callback();
   });
};
```

look into documentation: http://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/node/update/

> The replacement document can have different fields from the original
>   document.

but be care

> After the update, the document only contains the field or fields in
>   the replacement document.

So you need to get document, add you new fields and replace all the document

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$set` operator
This is official [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#set-top-level-fields)

so, what you have to do is

```
db.collection('collectionName').updateOne({ _id: ObjectId("5604f0150fe136e9292ee16a") }, { $set: { "Competitor": value_you_want_to_insert } })
```