# How to add a new key with increment value to all documents in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, database

I have collection with 50 documents. Is is possible to add one key (the same to all of them) and the value of this key is increment from 1 to 50. I mean for example the first document have a key: myId=1 , the second document myId=2 and so on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write a script inside the shell to loop through all the documents and run an update query for each document to add a new field.

This is how you could add a field to collection: 
[Add new field to a collection in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714216/add-new-field-to-a-collection-in-mongodb)

Referring the link above I wrote this, it should probably help

```
var i = 0;
db.collection.find().forEach(function(myDoc) {
    db.collection.update(myDoc, {$set : {"myId": i++ }}, false, true);  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var i=0;
db.collection.find().forEach(function(my){db.collection.update(my,{$set:{"newfield":i++}})})
```

It is still working with out the false and true flags of upsert and multi

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).