# MongoDB, how to add a unique index called "id"

Tags: mongodb, indexing, unique

I'm trying to add an index called "id" in my collection but it returns:

> E11000 duplicate key error index: collec.items.$id_1 dup key: { : -27
>   }

Is it before of a conflict between `_id` and `id`?
I really need the `id` field to be unique to avoid duplicates.

Comment: If you already have duplicate values in `id` field, remove them first and then try to add index

Answer (score 1):

> Is it before of a conflict between _id and id?

No, it's not a conflict. You're adding a unique index on a field that currently contains duplicate values (one of these duplicates is `-27`), so MongoDB complains with:

> E11000 duplicate key error index: collec.items.$id_1 dup key: { : **-27**
>   }

First remove the duplicate values and then try to add the index.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to update the existing `_id` with `id` ? Then mongo doesn't allow to do so.
Instead create a document. `_id` is unique identifier for mongo documents.

Creating the document with the unique `id` as you require,

```
>use db.docname.insert( { id:12345, name:"name" })
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
>db.idreplace.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("57592f1f2aa2b6057f3286ce"),
        "id" : 12345,
        "name" : "name"
}
```

OR

to add id to the existing document follow:
[Add new field to a collection in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714216/add-new-field-to-a-collection-in-mongodb)