# How to update data in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, database

How to update data in mongodb?

This is my actual structure of my collection

```
db.collection.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("557914833ac61e518e6103ab"),
    "dataValue" : {
        "value1" : [
            "value1 A",
            "value1 B"
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to insert like default in dataValue

```
db.collection.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("557914833ac61e518e6103ab"),
    "dataValue" : {
        "value1" : [
            "value1 A",
            "value1 B"
        ],
        "default" : [
            "default A",
            "default B"
        ]
    }
}
```

Please help me

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add new field to a collection in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714216/add-new-field-to-a-collection-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
db.collection.update(
   { _id: ObjectId("557914833ac61e518e6103ab") }, //update doc with this id
   { $set:
      {
        "dataValue.default": [
         "default A", 
         "default B" 
         ]
      }
   }
)
```

As per my comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

Syntax of update is (we're only using the `<query>` and `<update>` parts of this

```
db.collection.update(
   <query>,
   <update>,
   {
     upsert: <boolean>,
     multi: <boolean>,
     writeConcern: <document>,
     collation: <document>
   }
)
```

In your case, you need to use `$set`

`dataValue.default` uses dot notation to 'reach inside' the sub document, and set the property

Comment: db.collection.find({dataValue.value1}).pretty() this one not working

Comment: can yu give the correct syntax for getting dataValue.value1

Comment: what are you trying to find? What is the query?

Comment: db.collection.find({dataValue.value1}).pretty() i tried this one but getting SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

Comment: yes, because it's not valid!? what are you querying for... what do you want to query by?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148613/discussion-between-alex-and-arav-kt).

Comment: i want value1 data in my collection

Comment: for all documents? or just with id 557914833ac61e518e6103ab?

Comment: i want that particular dtaa

Comment: try this `db.collection.find( { }, { dataValue.value1: 1 } )`

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

Comment: add quotes - `db.collection.find( { }, { "dataValue.value1": 1 } )`

Answer (score 0):

This can be achived with a simple update with a $set operator

```
db.collection.update({"_id" : ObjectId("557914833ac61e518e6103ab")},
{ $set: {"dataValue.default" : [
            "default A",
            "default B"
        ]}})
```

Comment: db.collection.find({dataValue.value1}).pretty() this one not working