# how can i insert new value to existing record in mongodb?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I want to update my existing record with a new value in MongoDB, here I don't want to remove old value

[image: mongodb record]

here you can see that I have **punching detail** records and I want to add every time **machine number** and **punching time**

here is my model [image: this model contains puching detail class]

now I want to add new value every time there will be a puch in machine and 
can anyone have a solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714216/add-new-field-to-every-document-in-a-mongodb-collection

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Array data type for punching detail field and use MongoDB $push operator with update command.

For More Info: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommended to use Different Model for Punching Details and use mongodb ObjectId as a reference of Punching machine model.
You can also create a Array and append new document on each update but it will cause performance issue when your array is too large.
So you can use Punching_detail model as mentioned below

```
public class punching_detail {
   public string punchingModel_id {get;set;}
   public int machine_number {get;set;}
   public DateTime punching_time {get;set;}
}
```