# Add field to every document with existing data (move fields data to new field)

Tags: mongodb, nosql, field

I have almost no experience in SQL or noSQL.

I need to update every document so that my fields "Log*" are under the new field "Log"

I found some help from [this StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714216/add-new-field-to-every-document-in-a-mongodb-collection), but I am still wondering how to move the data.

Thank you very much

## Original document

`// collection: Services
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ccb4f99f4953d4894acbe79"),
    "Name" : "WebAPI",
    "LogPath" : "Product\\APIService\\",
    "LogTypeList" : [
        {
        "Name" : "ApiComCounter",
        "FileName" : "ApiComCounter.log"
    },
        {
        "Name" : "ApiService",
        "FileName" : "ApiService.log"
    }
    ]
}`

## Final Document

`// collection: Services
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ccb6fa2ae8f8a5d7037a5dd"),
    "Name" : "InvoicingService",
    "Log" : {
        "LogPath" : "Product\\APIService\\",
        "LogTypeList" : [
            {
            "Name" : "ApiComCounter",
            "FileName" : "ApiComCounter.log"
            },
            {
            "Name" : "ApiService",
            "FileName" : "ApiService.log"
            }
        ]
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

This requires **MongoDB 4.2** or higher:

```
db.<collection>.updateMany({}, [
  {$set: {"Log.LogPath": "$LogPath", "Log.LogTypeList": "$LogTypeList"}}, 
  {$unset: ["LogPath", "LogTypeList"]}
])
```