# Mongoose apply schema property changes to documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I am using mongoose and MongoDB for my Node.js project. I have basic schemas, and since the project is new I am updating some properties in the schemas. But, when I update a schema's some property (this may adding or removing property), the change is not updated to old documents that exist in the collection. How can I update older documents when changing a schema's properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say I created a new property on a UserSchema. The new property is called "test", it is of type String, and it is not required. This new property I added is a [non-breaking change](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/app-services/sync/data-model/update-schema/#breaking-vs.-non-breaking-change-quick-reference). None of my existing documents have changed any yet. I have yet to populate them.

Open the MongoSH (Mongo Shell).

Navigate to my database:
`show dbs;`
`use <db>`;

Update all documents with an unpopulated test field using [db.collection.updateMany()](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/crud/update/#update-multiple-documents):
`db.collection.updateMany( {test: null}, { $set: { test: “123” } })`

Similar Question found here:
[Add new field to every document in a MongoDB collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714216/add-new-field-to-every-document-in-a-mongodb-collection)