# How to add new field to mongodb schema?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I have a react application that performs CRUD operations on data stored in mongodb in the cloud.mongodb.com.

The schema of the data in my react looks like this:

```
const restaurantSchema = new Schema({
    "uuid": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "name": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "city": {
        "type": "string"
      }
}, {timestamps: true});
```

I would like to add a new field called "preference" of type number.

My questions are:

1. How do I add this new field of "preference"?
2. Can I give it a default value of say 1 when I add this new field? (There are 900 entries in the mongodb.)?
3. Can I give the "preference" value based on the order of the "name" field in ascending order?

thanks.

Comment: Found the answer in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714216/add-new-field-to-every-document-in-a-mongodb-collection

Answer (score 0):

You can add and remove fields in the schema using option `{ strict: false }`

**option: strict**

> The strict option, (enabled by default), ensures that values passed to our model constructor that were not specified in our schema do not get saved to the db.

```js
var thingSchema = new Schema({..}, { strict: false });
```

And also you can do this in update query as well

```js
Model.findOneAndUpdate(
  query,  //filter
  update, //data to update
  { //options
    returnNewDocument: true,
    new: true,
    strict: false
  }
)
```

You can check the documentation [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict)

Comment: Hi Sagar, I "want" to add the new field to the mongodb schema, so the data can look something like this:[
{
  uuid: 'some id here',
  name: 'restaurant name 1',
  city: 'some city1 here',
  preference: 1
  },
  {
  uuid: 'some id here2',
  name: 'St Andrews Hotel Fitzroy',
  city: 'some city2 here',
  preference: 2
  }
]