# MongoDB updateMany with $set does not work

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I have a simple sample database which I use to develop a simple micro framework for our application. To verify versioning works as expected, I need to update all documents by adding a new field. I used this [thread as guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714216/add-new-field-to-every-document-in-a-mongodb-collection), so what I'm doing should work.

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "63d95015f94d9a88ecbc1a00"
  },
  "Version": 1,
  "bookTitle": "Fancy Book 0",
  "author": "Author 0"
}
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "63d95015f94d9a88ecbc1a01"
  },
  "Version": 1,
  "bookTitle": "Fancy Book 1",
  "author": "Author 1"
}
... 8 more
```

Now when I run this in MongoSH:

```
db.Books.updateMany({}, {$set: {'NewField': true}})
```

I get this output:

```
{
  acknowledged: true,
  insertedId: null,
  matchedCount: 0,
  modifiedCount: 0,
  upsertedCount: 0
}
```

So what's the issue here? It does execute and it seemingly is correct, but no single document updates. The official documentation states that *{}* is a selector for all documents, so why does it not match even one of them?

Comment: The query looks OK. Are you sure this is the name of your DB?

Comment: Well I have a database called `Test` which I use in MongoDB Compass. The collection is called `Books` so everything should be fine...

Comment: The problem was that both MongoDB Compass and DataGrip by default run the shell with lower-case database name `test` but database names are case-sensitive. So switching to the right database with `use Test` fixes this. Not really user-friendly though that you can execute a command against a non-existing database without failure...