# Deleting a key/value from existing MongoDB entry

Tags: mongodb

I need to delete a certain key and value from every entry in a particular collection. I've looked into remove and that seems to be for only entire entries. Looking at update, I don't believe updating a particular key with null or an empty string would achieve what I'm trying to do. I'm very much a beginner with mongodb, so please excuse my ignorance.

Long story short, how can I turn

```
{
  "_id" : 1234,
  "name" : "Chris",
  "description" : "Awesome"
}
```

into

```
{
  "_id" : 1234,
  "name" : "Chris"
}
```

without deleting the entry and creating a new one, or using any non-mongodb commands? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove a field completely from Mongo?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851933/how-do-i-remove-a-field-completely-from-mongo)

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Try [`$unset`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) in a call to `update()`.

Like this:

```
db.collection_name.update({ _id: 1234 }, { $unset : { description : 1} })
```

And, as [vikneshwar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1318969/vikneshwar) commented, if you want to remove one field from all (or multiple) documents you can use `updateMany()` like this:

```
db.collection_name.updateMany({}, { $unset : { description : 1} })
```

Comment: To update all documents in a collection you can use: `db.collection_name.update({}, {$unset: { description:1}}, false, true);`  The last true is for multiple documents update

Comment: Newer versions support a more readable format: `db.example.update({},{$unset: {words:1}}, {multi: true})`

Comment: to update all documents, you can use updateMany instead of update like this ````db.collection_name.updateMany({}, { $unset : { description : 1} })````

Comment: What 1 does here? I mean mentioning just the key name seems to be enough. 1 is not making any specific meaning if there is no -1. Is there any possibility to have -1 as well along with "description" key?

Comment: Saved my time :) Thanks Bee San

Comment: @IrfanRaza 1 does not affect the operation, we can put anything there.

Comment: I did findOneAndUpdate just to get my data as response as : `findOneAndUpdate({ _id: userid },{$unset: {'Details.Expense.2022': 1}})` and my MongoDBCompass shows as an empty object for `Expense` but when I `res.send(result)` it showed an empty array for `2022`, why did that happen ???

Answer (score 4):

To reference a package and remove various "keys", try this

```
db['name1.name2.name3.Properties'].remove([ { "key" : "name_key1" }, { "key" : "name_key2" }, { "key" : "name_key3" } )]
```

Answer (score -10):

Also think about `upsert()` that will insert your row as a new document if `_id` does not exist or update the existing document if any.