# How do I remove a string from an array in a mongodb document?

Tags: mongodb

I've been having trouble with the problem of removing a string from an array in a mongodb document. For example I want to remove the entry "four" from the list field in the document below.

```
{
  "list" : [ "1", "2", "four", "five", "6"]
}
```

I know it seems very simple but I haven't been able to find a straight answer from the docs or previous questions. I've tried 5 or so commands to no avail using db.collection.update combined with the $pull and $mod modifiers. Any help?

I know, very rudimentary question.

Comment: I think your question is duplicated -> see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10146735/deleting-a-key-value-from-existing-mongodb-entry

Comment: try to `pull` like this `update({},{"$pull":{"list":"four"}})`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing specific items from array with MongoDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048424/removing-specific-items-from-array-with-mongodb)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use [$pull](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/operator/update/pull/) operator, please try the below query:

```
db.collection.update({
    { _id : id },
    { $pull: { "list": "four" } }
});
```

If you want to remove two or more elements from the array "list", you can do that with `$pull` operator, as well:

```
db.collection.update({
    { _id : id },
    { $pull: { list : { $in : [ "one", "four" ] } } }
});
```

Comment: Thanks that did it, I'm surprised I didn't think of that.

Comment: updated mongodb documentation link: [$pull](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/)