# Pull multiple values from array with mongo node native driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

The problem is :

```
doc1:{ 
  _id:1,
  array:['a','b','c']
},
doc2:{ 
  _id:2,
  array:['a','f','c']
}
```

I'm trying to remove `['a','b']` from the `array` field, using :

`.update({_id:1},{$pull:{array:['a','b']}})` but it doesn't seem to change anything, is there a different function I should use?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32002691/how-do-i-remove-a-string-from-an-array-in-a-mongodb-document/32002845#32002845

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [**`$pull`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) operator actually takes an argument as a "query", so the regular [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) applies here:

```
.update({ "_id": 1 },{ "$pull": { "array": { "$in": ["a","b"] } } },{ "multi": true })
```

Which basically asks to `$pull` "either" values "a" OR "b" from the array.

Also do not forget the "multi" option when you need to update more than one document in your statement.

Comment: @xShirase Of course it does. Remember it's a "query" and also remeber to ["accept"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) responses to your questions that "work".

Comment: lol you can't accept before 10minutes, and you've answerd in 2min

Comment: @xShirase LOL indeed. Damn you stackoverflow overlords, and your cheat protection guidelines! Just kidding. But don't go to sleep or just don't forget. :)