# How to remove an element from an array property in mongo collection

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am new to mongodb and need some guidance with a query.

I have a collection named **groups** which looks like below.

```
{

    "_id" : ObjectId("jkhjkhkjhkj"),
    "name" : "some_name",
    "members" : [ 
        "product:naxi", 
        "product:tina", 
        "product:natalia"
    ]

},

{

    "_id" : ObjectId("jhkjhkjhkjhk"),
    "name" : "some_other_name",
    "members" : [ 
        "product:naxi", 
        "product:albert", 
        "product:natalia"
    ]

},

{

    "_id" : ObjectId("678687hjbnbmnm"),
    "name" : "some_new_name",
    "members" : [ 
        "product:peter, 
        "product:sonya", 
        "product:tom"
    ]

}
```

I want to delete **product:naxi** where ever it's present in any item's member array in group collection.

Below is how the end result should look like -

```
{

    "_id" : ObjectId("jkhjkhkjhkj"),
    "name" : "some_name",
    "members" : [ 
        "product:tina", 
        "product:natalia"
    ]

},

{

    "_id" : ObjectId("jhkjhkjhkjhk"),
    "name" : "some_other_name",
    "members" : [ 
        "product:albert", 
        "product:natalia"
    ]

},

{

    "_id" : ObjectId("678687hjbnbmnm"),
    "name" : "some_new_name",
    "members" : [ 
        "product:peter", 
        "product:sonya", 
        "product:tom"
    ]

}
```

How can this be done using pymongo.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove a string from an array in a mongodb document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32002691/how-do-i-remove-a-string-from-an-array-in-a-mongodb-document)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) should do the trick:

```
db.groups.update(
    {},
    { $pull: { members: "product:naxi" } },
    { multi: true }
)
```