# How do I delete a field from a MongoDB collection by key?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a MongoDB database with a `settings` collection that I need to delete a field from by key. In the [docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/quick-start/quick-start#remove-a-document) I see that `deleteOne` accepts an Object [key, value].

How can I delete it with just the key since the value is unknown?

```
// key - req.params.key
db.collection('settings').deleteOne(???);
```

Comment: Check this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10146816/4782034

Comment: @Crowlex This was not in the docs when I was searching around so I assumed it was not for [Node.js](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native). Is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you question correctly. You want to delete a document where a particular field exists?

If so you can use the `$exists` element query operator.

Let's say the field name is `config`.

```
db.collection('settings').deleteOne({config: {$exists: true}})
```

Here is the source documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/

Comment: Thanks! Note your missing `}` near the end.