# How does $unset work?

Tags: mongodb

In the [mongo documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#remove-fields) unsetting a field is done with `$unset`. I can't quite grasp how it works, but it seems like it should be simple.

```
The following operation uses the $unset operator to remove the tags field:

db.books.update( { _id: 1 }, { $unset: { tags: 1 } } )
```

My confusion arises when setting what to unset. What is the value `1` for in the `$unset` clause?

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851933/how-do-i-remove-a-field-completely-from-mongo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the [`$unset` documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) :-

> The $unset operator deletes a particular field.
>
> Syntax : `{ $unset: { <field1>: "", ... } }`
>
> The specified value in the $unset expression (i.e. "") does not impact the operation.
>
> If the field does not exist, then $unset does nothing (i.e. no operation).

So you can use

```
db.books.update( { _id: 1 }, { $unset: { tags: 1 } } )
```

OR

```
db.books.update( { _id: 1 }, { $unset: { tags: 0 } } )
```

OR

```
db.books.update( { _id: 1 }, { $unset: { tags: "" } } )
```

All the above queries will delete `tags` field.

Hope your doubt is clear now.

Comment: In the doc, the explanation is simple: "The specified value in the $unset expression (i.e. "") does not impact the operation."
More here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/

Answer (score 3):

`{$unset : { tags : 1 } }` will clear the field `tags` from the document. The value `1` is just to tell that, clear this field `tags` from the document.

If you want to clear multiple fields, you need to write `{$unset : { tags : 1, randomField : 1} }` and like that.

You can refer [official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) of $unset for further info.

According to the documentation:

> The $unset operator deletes a particular field. Consider the
>   following syntax:
>
> { $unset: { field1: "", ... } }
>
> The specified value in the $unset
>   expression (i.e. "") does not impact the operation.
>
> If the field does not exist, then $unset does nothing (i.e. no
>   operation).
>
> When used with $ to match an array element, $unset replaces the
>   matching element with null rather than removing the matching element
>   from the array.

Comment: What would happen if I used 0 instead of 1? Does the actual value hold any relevance?

Comment: The actual value 0/1 doesn't hold any relevance. But, i think that is the way that query was modeled. See this for more reference : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/

Answer (score 0):

The $unset operator deletes a particular field.