# Delete a key in all the documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, robo3t

I have modified a schema (ie, `users`) by deleting a key (ie, `ips`). Thus I want to delete this key in all the documents in the database.

For example, in `mongo console` or `Robo 3T`, `db.getCollection('users').find({})` returns all the users. Some of them contain the key `ips`. Does anyone know how to remove `ips` in the console or Robo 3T?

Comment: Try `db.getCollection('users').update(
   { },
   { $unset: { ips: "" } }
)`

Comment: Are you sure about that? I just tested, it did not work... Previously `ips` was defined as `[{ type: String }]` @Veeram

Comment: try this one `db.getCollection('users').update({},{ips : undefind})`

Comment: What are the data types of `users` and `ips`?

Comment: `ips` is `[{ type: String }]`, `users` is an Object that has several keys including `ips`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove a field completely from a MongoDB document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851933/how-to-remove-a-field-completely-from-a-mongodb-document)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Veeram already posted you can run a regular update with `$unset` just add `multi: true` in the options to update `all` documents, otherwise it will update just one

```
db.users.update(
  { }, // where
  { $unset: { ips: 1 } }, // change what
  { multi: true } // options
)
```

Answer (score 2):

> **Update Multiple Documents**
>
> To update multiple documents, set the `multi` option to `true`. Refer [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-multiple-documents)

```
db.getCollection('users').update(
  { },
  { $unset: { ips: 1 } },
  { multi: true } 
)
```