# Delete an element in an array contained in object contained in array in mongoose

Tags: mongoose

I have a Document with this attribute in mongoose like that:

```
mapping: [
 { a: 1, b: [1,2,3] }, 
 { d: 1, c: [1,2,3] }
]
```

My question is, how can I delete the value 3 contained in `b`. I have `b` value and the number '3'. And if `b` is empty then delete the entire object `{a: 1, b: [1,2,3]}`

```
Test.findOneAndUpdate(
    { "mapping.a" : 1 }, 
    { "$pull": { "a.$.b": "3" } } 
)
```

I try this but I need when `b` is empty delete the object.

Comment: Can you show what you have written already? Would help to know what you have, and determine what is needed.

Comment: I edited with my code example

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6852039/4515720 I think that it will put you in the right direction