# How to delete object to use mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I want to remove object to use mongodb.

First find ID and second remove only AAA field.

I tried it to use findOneAndDelete function. but It wrong worked.

It worked Find(OK) and Delete query(false).

I want to keep other filed and remove target filed(AAA).

please share your idea.

below example code.

```
{ id: 6319, AAA : Object , BBB : Object , CCC : Object },

result = await User.findOneAndDelete({id : 6319 },{ projection : { AAA : Object } });
```

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851933/how-to-remove-a-field-completely-from-a-mongodb-document

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I resolve it.
result = await User.findOneAndUpdate({id : 6319 },{ $unset: { [AAA] : 1 } });

Answer (score 0):

Please try using $unset to remove the field