# How to remove field from mongo documents using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to remove the particular field from mongo document using mongoose.But it's not working.

Here my mongo document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5da80eb605320f441c41e340"),
    "name" : "TEST1-_-m3mkf9",
    "users" : [ 
        {
            "formStatus" : "assigned",
            "form" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5da80eb505320f441c41e33d"),
                }
             ],
        }
    ]
}
```

Here my code:

```
await Promise.all(
  Form.update(
    { _id: "5d8da115e222df7ebc066175" },
    { $pull: { users: 1 } },
    { safe: true }
  )
)
  .then(async val => {})
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

I want to remove the users field from mongo document. How can i do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851933/how-to-remove-a-field-completely-from-a-mongodb-document). Check answers

Answer (score 0):

The below should work.

```
await Form.findByIdAndUpdate('5d8da115e222df7ebc066175', {
    $unset: { users: '' }
  });
```

Comment: getting TypeError: #<Query> is not iterable

Comment: did you put inside a async function. also run the code inside a try catch block and remove all Promise.all, .then .catch.

Comment: i need to do it inside async function.