# how to delete the PEO field in angular api

Tags: angular, mongodb, typescript

How to delete the field of PEO for api :

```
{
  "program_objective": "",
  "program_type": "Post Graduate",
  "creation_date": "2020-01-04T04:45:28.418Z",
  "dstatus": "",
  "_id": "5e101e26a96cc905745721b0",
  "program_name": "Hardware",
  "short_code": "Hdw",
  "program_induc_date": "2020-01-28T18:30:00.000Z",
  "program_cat": "Certificate",
  "program_years": "0",
  "program_months": "6",
  "depart_id1": "Msc IT ",
  "PEO": [
    {
      "_id": "5e12c9703a1a5d2f707aee71",
      "peo": "Hardware",
      "weight": 212
    },
    {
      "_id": "5e12c9703a1a5d2f707aee70",
      "peo": "Hardware",
      "weight": 212
    }
  ],
  "Name": [],
  "PO": [
    {
      "_id": "5e12c9703a1a5d2f707aee6f",
      "poName": "Basic and Discipline specific knowledge: Apply knowledge of basic mathematics, science and engineering fundamentals and engineering specialization to solve the engineering problems"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5e12c9703a1a5d2f707aee6e",
      "poName": "Problem analysis: Identify and analyse well-defined engineering problems using codified standard methods."
    },
    {
      "_id": "5e12c9703a1a5d2f707aee6d",
      "poName": "Design/ development of solutions: Design solutions for well-defined technical problems and assist with the design of systems components or processes to meet specified needs."
    },
    {
      "_id": "5e12c9703a1a5d2f707aee6c",
      "poName": "Engineering Tools, Experimentation and Testing: Apply modern engineering tools and appropriate technique to conduct standard tests and measurements."
    },
    {
      "_id": "5e12c9703a1a5d2f707aee6b",
      "poName": "Engineering practices for society, sustainability and environment: Apply appropriate technology in context of society, sustainability, environment and ethical practices."
    },
    {
      "_id": "5e12c9703a1a5d2f707aee6a",
      "poName": "Project Management: Use engineering management principles individually, as a team member or a leader to manage projects and effectively communicate about well-defined engineering activities."
    },
    {
      "_id": "5e12c9703a1a5d2f707aee69",
      "poName": "Life-long learning: Ability to analyse individual needs and engage in updating in the context of technological changes."
    }
  ],
  "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: I had to edit your question from your posted answer, Please do not post anything in answer, edit your question if you've to update something. So do you want to delete `PEO` array field ? But your title says fetch !! What do you want to do ?

Comment: sss i want  to delete PEO field

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove a field completely from a MongoDB document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851933/how-to-remove-a-field-completely-from-a-mongodb-document)